# Java 7 to Java 8 breaks our Lift JSON parser 2.6-RC1

Tags: java, json, scala, lift, lift-json

I have a weird Scala runtime error running Lift JSON parser 2.6-RC1 and Java8.

The code for the error is at https://github.com/listatree/lift-json-java8

The stacktrace error is at: https://github.com/listatree/lift-json-java8/blob/master/stacktrace.txt

The error states a ScapaSigParserError validating the class coming from the Lift JSON parser.

I know that the Lift JSON parser does extreme things with reflection and/or the AST tree, but so far was working.

NOTE: If I tested with java 8 on a Mac OS X it works, if I tested with java 8 on a Linux machine it breaks (sometimes). With java 7 works all the time

Comment: The exact versions:

Java 8u25 (server version for Linux 64 bits)
Debian GNU/Linux 7.7
Scala 2.11.2
Lift JSON 2.6-RC1

JVM startup parameters: -Xms3072m -Xmx3072m -server -Xss8m -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=30

Comment: I'd like to make sure this gets looked at by the right person.  Would you mind posting it to the Lift google group?  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liftweb